# Start script after ng serve is up

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have written a script that takes screenshots of my angular application. The Problem is the script only works if i start ng serve manually before my script. My question is can i tell ng serve to start a script if the development server is up and running. I tried `ng serve  && node screenshot-generation.js` but the screenshot-generation script is not excuted because ng serve is not finished.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since your server does not exit and does not produce exit code, second process is not launched. I see at least two approaches to resolving this task:

1) Launch service1, do not wait for exit, sleep for several seconds and launch service2 like `ng serve & sleep 5s && node screenshot-generation.js` (please note one `&`). Downside is that you can't be sure that service1 is up and running.

2) Make a little node wrapper which launches your server1 via child process exec, waits to ensure that it is running and then launch service2.

Comment: How to insure that it is running by using child.exec ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do there, but you are running two servers with those commands.

What you could do is serve your application with Node, and not with ng serve.

Is you script made to make a screenshot just once, for your own sake, or is it something you will put as available for your users ? Because if it's the first one, just open another tab and you should be good.

Comment: My screenshot generation script is using https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer to generate the screenshots. But puppeteer can only navigate thru my app if the dev server is up and running. The script should only generate the screenshots once and then finish.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question : do you want to run it once, or do you want your users to run it ? If once, simply open another tab and launch it !